# Creating a "Subgroup" within a Group of Contacts?

Tags: lync, lync-2010

Is it possible to have a group inside of a group in Lync? I cannot seem to find a way to do it.

For example, I've got 5 groups, `Project A`, `Project B`, `Project C`, `Project 1`, `Project 2`.

Projects A-C are iOS & Android developers and I infrequently need to contact them. Projects 1 and 2 are desktop developers that I frequently contact and is fine as is.

Ultimately, I'd like Lync to look sort of like this:

```
 Project 1
      Person One
      Person Two
      etc...
 Project 2
      Person One
      Person Two
      etc...
 Mobile
      Project A
           Person One
      Project B
           Person Two
      Project C
           etc...
```

Then I could expand A, B, or C to see the members of those teams.

Basically, since it's just such a bloated-looking app I'm trying to minimize the amount of space consumed and since I won't frequently need the Mobile devs I don't need to see the groups all the time.

Comment: Would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible - Microsoft in their wisdom decided on a flat model for the groups. Nesting is not allowed.

I know - it's rubbish isn't it?

Comment: The mind truly does boggle. Really hate Communicator :(